# How can I check the memory usage of an iPython notebook?

Tags: memory, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have several iPython notebooks open, and I would like to find out how much ram is used by each one. 
It would be nice to do this from within the notebook itself.

Comment: There is a python package for doing this. I'm not sure how compatible it is with ipython notebooks.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler